# Adding menu item when clicking on package

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I need to add an item to the menu that opens when I right click on any package.

what I did until now was adding those lines to the plugin.xml:

```xml
 <objectContribution id="myPlugin.menu" objectClass="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragment">

    <menu id="myPlugin.menu1" label="My New Item"></menu>

    <action
          class="myPlugin.rightClickMenu.NewActivityAction"
          enablesFor="1"
          id="myPlugin.newAction"
          label="Create New Activity"
          menubarPath="myPlugin.menu1/group1">
    </action>

 </objectContribution>
```

in short,
this is working excellent and does everything I need.
it shows "My New Item" in the menu that opens when I right click the package.
does not work when I click any other folders, files, or project, very good.

but,

this is deprecated...

I have found another way for doing this:

```xml
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer?before=additions">

<separator name="separetor1" visible="true"></separator>

  <command commandId="openMyMenu"
    label="My New Item" style="push">       
  </command>

</menuContribution>
```

```xml
<command defaultHandler="myPlugin.rightClickMenu.NewActivityAction"

  id="openMyMenu" name="createActivity">

</command>
```

this is not deprecated,
but this shows me the "My New Item" in the menu always no matter what I right click.
even for JRE System library menu.

can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `visibleWhen` element in your command in the menuContribution:

```xml
<command commandId="openMyMenu"
   label="My New Item" style="push">       
   <visibleWhen>
        <iterate
              ifEmpty="false"
              operator="or">
           <adapt
                type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragment">
           </adapt>
       </iterate>
   </visibleWhen>
</command>
```

Comment: is there a way of adding my menu item to the: right-click->New menu?

Comment: Use the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point to add to the New menu. Don't forget to accept answers that solve your problem (click the tick mark).

Comment: I know how to add new wizards to the 'File->New->Project'. my question is: is it possible to add item to the right click menu (only over packages) and then my item will be there?